# Krusader crashed on Mac OSX 10.7.2

Tags: macos, dbus

i've installed krusader via macports but i'm unable to run krusader.

```
w-4jesc:web_cms_dms w-4jesc$ /Applications/MacPorts/KDE4/krusader.app/Contents/MacOS/krusader
KGlobal::locale::Warning your global KLocale is being recreated with a valid main component instead of a fake component, this usually means you tried to call i18n related functions before your main component was created. You should not do that since it most likely will not work 
krusader(97879)/KSharedDataCache ensureFileAllocated: This system misses support for posix_fallocate() -- ensure this partition has room for at least 10547296 bytes. 
krusader(97879)/KSharedDataCache: Unable to find an appropriate lock to guard the shared cache.  This *should* be essentially impossible. :( 
krusader(97879)/KSharedDataCache: Unable to perform initial setup, this system probably does not really support process-shared pthreads or semaphores, even though it claims otherwise. 
krusader(97879)/KSharedDataCache: Unable to unmap shared memory segment 0x1142d2000 
Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!
krusader(97879)/kdeui (kdelibs): Session bus not found 
To circumvent this problem try the following command (with Linux and bash) 
export $(dbus-launch) 
KCrash: Application 'krusader' crashing...
KCrash: Attempting to start /opt/local/lib/kde4/libexec/drkonqi.app/Contents/MacOS/drkonqi from kdeinit
sock_file=/Users/w-4jesc/Library/Preferences/KDE/socket-w-4jesc.local/kdeinit4__tmp_launch-URcTjs_org.x_0
Warning: connect() failed: : No such file or directory
KCrash: Attempting to start /opt/local/lib/kde4/libexec/drkonqi.app/Contents/MacOS/drkonqi directly
QProcess: Destroyed while process is still running.
drkonqi(97882)/KSharedDataCache ensureFileAllocated: This system misses support for posix_fallocate() -- ensure this partition has room for at least 10547296 bytes. 
drkonqi(97882)/KSharedDataCache: Unable to find an appropriate lock to guard the shared cache.  This *should* be essentially impossible. :( 
drkonqi(97882)/KSharedDataCache: Unable to perform initial setup, this system probably does not really support process-shared pthreads or semaphores, even though it claims otherwise. 
drkonqi(97882)/KSharedDataCache: Unable to unmap shared memory segment 0x1145ea000 
Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!
drkonqi(97882)/kdeui (kdelibs): Session bus not found 
To circumvent this problem try the following command (with Linux and bash) 
export $(dbus-launch)
```

dbus is already loaded:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist
org.freedesktop.dbus-session: Already loaded
```

has every one a idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist
```

Comment: Please add some description to your solution. Why it solves the OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

MacPorts installer specifically says to start dbus without sudo:

```
 # Don't forget that dbus needs to be started as the local 
 # user (not with sudo) before any KDE programs will launch
 # To start it run the following command:                  
 # launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist
```